# mysql: how to create a date column from another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query that retrieves a column which type is a date, but based on this column I also need to create another column in my query which takes year and month of this mentioned column, and as day use 1.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT 
    forecast_id,
    name,
    property_id,
    property_name,
    DATE(YEAR(last_day_of_month), MONTH(last_day_of_month), 1) AS forecast_month,
    last_day_of_month,
FROM table_name;
```

I am getting an error, and I have no idea how I can get this column which takes the same year and month of one column that exist in my table, and just changes the day.

The error I am getting is:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' MONTH(last_day_of_month), 1) AS forecast_month,     last_day_of_month,     COUN' at line 6   0.00075 sec

Comment: well, you could start by giving us the error you get?

Comment: @Jan, I just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATE in MySQL has no three-argument version - thus the error.

You should be able to do this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(
   CONCAT(YEAR(last_day_of_month),'-',MONTH(last_day_of_month),'-',1)
    , '%Y-%m-%d') as firstOfMonth 
 FROM table_name;
```

Another apporach would be to first go to the last day of that month (that's already in last_day_o_month?) , then add one day (1.st of next month) and then go back one month:

```
 SELECT  date_add(date_add(last_day_of_month, interval 1 DAY),interval -1 MONTH)
```

Comment: this works properly, what about of performance? I see the time increases a lot.

Comment: can you specify "a lot" - how did you measure? How many rows / how frequent your selection are we talking about? Of cause this is a bit backwards for first making a string and then parsing it again...

Comment: so without this column, the duration/fetch time is 0.0078 sec / 0.000024, and when adding your answer 0.0081 / 0.000031.

Comment: So 0.3ms added? Hmmm. You see my second solution?

Comment: thanks for providing a second option to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to just subtract the day of the month:

```
select last_day_of_month + interval (1 - day(last_day_of_month)) day
```

Note:  You need to convert to a `date` if there could be a time component.

Comment: this works, but how can I set day to 1, it is like this is subtracting 1 day to the `last_day_of_month`

Comment: your answer is really good in performance, just the fact of the day is missing to solve my question, and there are no time component involved.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf . . . This sets the day of the month to "1".

Comment: no it doesn't. let's say for value `2017-03-31` in `last_day_of_month` the value I am getting is `2017-04-30`.